# Force UINavigationBar to overlay container below instead of pushing it down

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

I was just wondering if there is a simple way to specify whether a `UINavigationBar` should overlay its content when shown. I currently have a `UINavigationController` that contains a custom `UIViewController` with a `UIScrollView`, which contains a `UIPageViewController` (I wanted a zooming/scrollable `UIPageViewController`).

When I call:

```
[self setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

From within my `UINavigationController`, the `UINavigationBar` animates in, but pushes the custom container with all its content down, instead of overlaying it.

The bar is set to translucent and I've tried all the settings I can think of. I changed the `extendEdges` settings in the child view controllers and that resized the content when the navigation bar came in, instead of pushing it down. But I still can't work out how to get it to overlay instead.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, apologies. This just reveals how little I know about iOS programming...

I noticed that the container's view origin y value was -44. So adding the following within my container class:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect boundsRect = self.view.bounds;
    boundsRect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    self.view.bounds = boundsRect;
}
```

Results in the view staying at the top of the screen, so the `UINavigationBar` overlays it nicely when it appears.

EDIT: Actually the proper way appears to be just calling:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: Man I love you!!!  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO; was exactly was I have been searching for hour. Thanks for sharing this :)